# I need help understanding what the following code does

Tags: c++

```
while(u!=1)
{
    if(u%2==0)
    {
        u=u/2;
    }else{
    u=u*3+1;
    }
    count = count + 1;
}
```

Can someone explain to me what does this count? It seems pretty simple but I just can't figure it out.

Comment: Which line is causing you trouble?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collatz_conjecture

Comment: `count`, as the name suggests, counts number of times you went through the loop.

Comment: I need to understand what this does so I can implement it somewhere. It's for an exam.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this looks like a implementation to test the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collatz_conjecture

if a number is even, its divided by 2, if its odd, its multiplied by 3 and 1 is added.

the conjecture aussumes it will lead to 1 for each positive integer, but there is no proof yet